# how to get string from array using angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var array = [
      {id: 1, text: "one"},
      {id: 2, text: "two"},
      {id: 3, text: "three"},
      {id: 4, text: "four"},
      {id: 5, text: "five"}
    ];

var name = array.find(function(item){
          return item.id == $localStorage.id;
 });
```

returns me {id: 2, text: "two"}
expected two only string nothing else should print

Comment: `find` will return the object that satisfy the condition

Comment: Another note: if id is unique you can use js object intstead array: 
var data = {"1": "one", "2" : "two", "3": "three", "4": "four", "5": "five"};
and then write:
var name = data[$localStorage.id];
It will be simpler and faster.

Comment: Add .text after }) like this: var name = array.find(function(item) { return item.id == $localStorage.id; }).text;

Answer (score 2):

You can first find the object and then get the `text` property by checking if the `find()` operation actually returned a object or it is `undefined`.

```js
var array = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "one"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "two"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "three"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "four"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "five"
  }
];

var findObj = array.find(function(item) {
  return item.id == 2;
});
//check if findObj is defined or not
var name = findObj? findObj.text: null;
console.log(name);
```

You can also use destructuring to get that `text` value directly from `find()` if you are sure the object exist for that localStorage value. Otherwise, it will raise error.

```js
var array = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "one"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "two"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "three"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "four"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "five"
  }
];

var {text} = array.find(function(item) {
  return item.id == 2;
});
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve property text of found object:

```
var object = array.find(function(item){
   return item.id === $localStorage.id;
});

var name = object.text;
```

Comment: Will definitely not work. `array.find returns the element at the array index where thee boolean returns true.

Comment: The naming of the variable "object" is not ideal but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

What you did returns the element at the position where `item.id == $localStorage.id`. If you want to get the text, then after the element is returned in `var name`, you just do `name.text` because `array.find()` returns the element that passed the logical operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). This way you can customize your filtered result the way you want.

```js
var array = [
      {id: 1, text: "one"},
      {id: 2, text: "two"},
      {id: 3, text: "three"},
      {id: 4, text: "four"},
      {id: 5, text: "five"}
    ];

var name = array.filter(a=> a.id === 2).map(b=> {return b.text});
console.log(name)
```

Comment: @Thomas, this will work for both the cases single and multiple filters, later on when you have multiple conditions like id and text both, this will be helpful.

Comment: imo. Premature optimization. And I don't know wether I've ever had to combine a `filter` on a list with an element lookup by ID. For me it's ususally one or the other.

Comment: @G2Jakhmola why not?

Comment: It surely depends on the size of the array and its purpose however I think filter and map is an overkill in this case.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I don't think so it would overkill. Can you explain?

Comment: Because .map() serves a different purpose. Why combine 2 functions when you can use something fit for purpose that's always going to be no.1 in benchmarks, no matter the size of an array.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk As i said earlier this will serve multiple purposes, I admit 1 filter `find` would work straightly without any issue,

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use es6 syntax, you can write like this.
You did everything good except, you needed to get specific object value.

```
const array = [
  { id: 1, text: "one" },
  { id: 2, text: "two" },
  { id: 3, text: "three" },
  { id: 4, text: "four" },
  { id: 5, text: "five" }
];

// So here i use same find as you did.

let object = array.find(item => {
  return item.id == $localStorage.id;
});

// And assigning text property of object to variable 'name'
// since object, can be undefined, using OR empty object, 
// so no error will be thrown if so.

let { text: name } = object || {};
console.log(name);
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find:

The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way to get `text` attribute value while using find by `id`

```js
var array = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "one"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "two"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "three"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "four"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "five"
  }
];

var name = array.find(function(item) {
  return item.id == 2;
}).text;

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

find will return the object that satisfy the condition

```
var object = array.find(function(item) {
  return item.id == $localStorage.id;
});



var name = object? object.text: null;
console.log(name);
```